# The meaning of "spinning" in this word combination

Tags: word-meaning

My translator has not been giving a result for *spinning* which makes sense in the following sentence:

> He was spinning drunken fantasies of something.

Translator said that the "spinning" is a part of fish-rod device. It is nonsense in my case :). Any ideas?

Comment: You have to look up the verb to spin in the dictionary, not spinning. In your sentence "to spin" has the meaning of "to make up".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is derived from the idiom *spinning a yarn* which means telling a story.

Woollen yarn is spun from the wool.  The word yarn can also mean a story, particularly a spoken tale.  Thus, *spinning a yarn* is used to describe someone telling a story.

By extension, your quotation relates to drunken ramblings, telling a story, spinning fantasies.